# Поиск строк по ключу и запись в их в файл

Tags: php

Есть текстовый файл такого вида:

```
F FSD TX foi2j9grh89h24utn
fsd F dsfEU mgj3098hivnfd9uhgb
fsdf  UL h3t8uteih938ht0geg
fsdf sfsdf UY vj943u09vjdiofngoid
Fdsfh TX gfiosjfgioj3ghh
```

Требуется найти и выписать все строки в которых есть слово "TX".
Помогите написать.

Answer (score -1):

```
$RESULT = array();
$handle = @fopen("test.txt", "r");  // Файл
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if (mb_strpos($buffer, 'TX') !== false) {
        // Если слово, то можно с пробелами:
        //if (mb_strpos($buffer, ' TX ') !== false) {
            $RESULT[] = rtrim($buffer);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_dump($RESULT);  // Результат
```